# Facebook Developer Alert

Tags: facebook

I received this alert at this morning

Your app asks for read and write permissions at the same time. You should only ask for write permissions when a user tries to share something to Facebook. Please update your app accordingly. Read our best practices for more details.

I am asking only email and publish_stream.What is this ? I am not asking read_stream permission.How can I resolve it ?

Answer (score 0):

**email** is a read permission and **publish_stream** is a write permission. And yes, with the new rules; you should ask for read and write permissions separately.

Its quite simple- ask only for the **email** permission initially, then at the step where you are actually posting, ask for the **publish_stream** permission there.

To ask for permissions again, you simply have to call the **facebook login** again with the new permission.

Good luck!

Comment: But I am doing facebook register.I am getting email from users facebook account,and posting their walls something like "I am registered"

Comment: Issue is same :) Facebook developer alert continuing

Comment: So when the register is successfull, then call the login function with `publish_stream` and then post to the wall. Simple enough! :)